# Message Access Profile (MAP) compatible with Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to use the Bluetooth Message Access Profile (MAP) with the Bluetooth Low Energy  (Bluetooth Smart) technology?  From a quick read of the specification, it seems that MAP is only available on the traditional BT side.  That would prohibit using MAP + LE for things like smart watches.  Is this the case?

Comment: You are correct that MAP and traditional BT profiles are not compatible with BLE.  BLE profiles are all GATT based.  In some cases, such as HID, there is standardization of a new LE HID profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Message access profile cannot be supported over Bluetooth LE. Bluetooth LE is meant for transfer of small packets while in MAP ,large packets are send across device. MAP is a OBEX based profile which depends on RFCOMM and L2CAP, RFCOMM is not available on BT LE.

Comment: Thanks! It is worth considering also MAP gives access to data that a developer normally would not have access to, like text messages and all other notification text. It is not clear to me what the security implications are. We were considering building a device that, as part of its functionality, would route the MAP data back to an MFI BT iOS app (since BT LE wasn't an option). I am not 100% sure that app would have been approved, even though the reason for routing data back was legit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the answer based on reading the Bluetooth spec for MAP [1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=215400&ei=A6U3UKrzHK3qiQLBmoHQAg&usg=AFQjCNEqBPURzpAHujZMvoG-ps5_zrXRQw&sig2=G4IYYvet62fCWt_MDLZFfA) and others' feedback is that MAP is only supported in traditional Bluetooth, not Bluetooth LE.  That's bad news for small battery powered information devices like smart watches that are otherwise perfect for MAP.